# Is there a way I can simplify adding a C# binding to a grid in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have some code that looks like this

```
var g1 = new ButtonGrid();
g1.SetBinding(ButtonGrid.BtnStateProperty, new Binding(nameof(_vm.TimeState)));
```

What I would like to do is to be able to simplify that to something like this:

```
var g1 = new ButtonGrid();
g1.Bind(ButtonGrid.BtnStateProperty, _vm.TimeState);
```

ButtonGrid inherits from Grid so I wonder if I can make something like a grid extension.

Maybe it's not possible but I would like to get some advice.

Comment: sure, create your own extension method.  But the difference between the two options seems pretty trivial and not much of a simplification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy way to do this.

All that is needed is to add

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Markup;
```

That does everything that I need.  I hope my answer helps someone.